# USB 3.0 port not working properly

Tags: usb, 16.04

I am having some problems with a USB flash drive when my computer resumes from suspend.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS L521X. This laptop has three USB ports, 2 times USB 2.0 and 1 time USB 3.0. I had the flash drive plugged into the USB 3.0 port and I was editing a document stored on that flash drive. Then I put the computer into suspend and on resuming, I went ahead to make changes to the document (which was still open), however an error message appeared saying that the path to the document could not be found.

The thing is the flash drive icon still appears in the dock and when I click on it, only then it mounts. Then I can go ahead and save the document. On the other hand if the flash drive was plugged into the USB 2.0 ports, I never had this problem.

I am not sure if this is a bug, or if this is just the way USB 3.0 ports work on Ubuntu. I should also say, that I tried out the USB 3.0 port with a keyboard and mouse and it worked the way it should. When I resumed from suspend, the devices worked as normal. The error only appeared for flash drives.

Comment: Take a look at the output of  `dmesg -T` just after resuming and see if it shows any USB-related messages or errors especially near the end of the output. If you can find the point where the suspend happens in the output, then maybe there will be a message about it unmounting the drive. The `-T` option makes the time stamps human readable.